# How to update all but one pod

Tags: cocoa, cocoapods

Is it possible to leave one pod untouched during `pod install` and `pod update`?

`pod update <POD>` is not an option.

Comment: You could update your podfile to be explicit that you don't want the version to change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually can use `pod update [NAMES...]` to update specific pods. You can see this in `pod update --help`